# How safe is rsync --remove-source-files?

Tags: rsync

I want to move some files using rsync, but it's vital that the files are intact at the destination before removing the source files. The thing is, I can't find any information telling me how rsync decides that a file has been transferred correctly: I'll need it to be properly checksummed.
Anyone know how rsync does it?

Comment: I am pretty confident that if it can't pass any attributes for instance, it won't accept the file as being copied. succesfully But why don't you give it a try by killing the session mid-copy? After all the algorithm might be the same but the implementations differ.

Comment: In answer to "how safe is it": how good is your disaster recovery plan?

Comment: Rock solid on one side of the sync, non-existant at the other. And unfortunately I don't have control over that side :-( Hence the reason I'd like to make any failures as unlikely as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `--checksum` to ensure files that have the same size & times on source and destination are not skipped. Then, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm):

> The recipient splits its copy of the file into fixed-size non-overlapping chunks and computes two checksums for each chunk: the MD4 hash, and a weaker 'rolling checksum'. (Version 30 of the protocol, released with rsync version 3.0.0, now uses MD5 hashes rather than MD4.[14]) It sends these checksums to the sender.

Answer (score 4):

The section about `--checksum` in the manpage says rsync always verifies the ckecksum of the received file to consider it complete (even when `--checksum` is not used):

> Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file checksum that is generated as the file is transferred, but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has nothing to do with this option's before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?" check.